# Keyboard shrinking EditText

Tags: android, android-layout, android-softkeyboard

I have three `EditText` in my layout. When i click on any of them then it shrinks my layout and the second layout is barely visible. I want that when i click on second layout ("Dear Parents"), keyboard should overlap the last edittext (teachers name) and when i click on last edittext then it should appear above keyboard.
Here are the screenshots

[image]
[image]

and here is the code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/actionbar_title_color"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/include"
        layout="@layout/toolbar" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        card_view:cardElevation="10sp"
        card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"

            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/filebinder" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="14"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">


                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="6"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/dateDiary"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                            android:text="30 July"
                            android:textColor="#03a9f4"
                            android:textSize="20sp" />

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="1dp"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                            android:background="#03a9f4" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="@drawable/diarybookmark" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <ScrollView
                    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp">

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/diaryHeading"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_margin="10dp"
                        android:ems="5"
                        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                        android:hint="Diary Heading"
                        android:inputType="textPersonName"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:textSize="18sp" />
                </ScrollView>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical">


                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/diaryTeacherName"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                        android:hint="Teacher\'s Name..."
                        android:textSize="16sp" />


                    <at.markushi.ui.CircleButton
                        android:id="@+id/addDiaryEntry"
                        android:layout_width="74dip"
                        android:layout_height="74dip"
                        android:layout_gravity="right"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_tick"
                        app:cb_color="@color/actionbar_title_color"
                        app:cb_pressedRingWidth="8dip"
                        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/diaryContent"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_above="@+id/addDiaryEntry"
                        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/scrollView"
                        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/scrollView"
                        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/scrollView"
                        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                        android:gravity="top"
                        android:hint="Enter Diary Note...\n\n\n\n"
                        android:text="Dear Parents,"
                        android:textSize="14sp" />


                </RelativeLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

and here is my manifest

```
<activity
            android:name=".DiaryEntry.DiaryEntryTeacherActivity"
            android:label="DiaryEntry"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"></activity>
```

Comment: have you tried adding the child view of `CardView` as `ScrollView`?

Comment: No, i think i should try that..

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `ScrollView` as;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/actionbar_title_color"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/include"
        layout="@layout/toolbar" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroll_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            card_view:cardElevation="10sp"
            card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"

                android:background="#ffffff"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/filebinder" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="14"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">


                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="6"
                            android:orientation="vertical">

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/dateDiary"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                                android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                                android:text="30 July"
                                android:textColor="#03a9f4"
                                android:textSize="20sp" />

                            <LinearLayout
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="1dp"
                                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                                android:background="#03a9f4" />

                        </LinearLayout>

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:background="@drawable/diarybookmark" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <ScrollView
                        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="10dp">

                        <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/diaryHeading"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:layout_margin="10dp"
                            android:ems="5"
                            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                            android:hint="Diary Heading"
                            android:inputType="textPersonName"
                            android:textAlignment="center"
                            android:textColor="#000000"
                            android:textSize="18sp" />
                    </ScrollView>

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:orientation="vertical">


                        <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/diaryTeacherName"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                            android:hint="Teacher\'s Name..."
                            android:textSize="16sp" />


                        <at.markushi.ui.CircleButton
                            android:id="@+id/addDiaryEntry"
                            android:layout_width="74dip"
                            android:layout_height="74dip"
                            android:layout_gravity="right"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_tick"
                            app:cb_color="@color/actionbar_title_color"
                            app:cb_pressedRingWidth="8dip"
                            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

                        <EditText
                            android:id="@+id/diaryContent"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_above="@+id/addDiaryEntry"
                            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/scrollView"
                            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/scrollView"
                            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/scrollView"
                            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                            android:gravity="top"
                            android:hint="Enter Diary Note...\n\n\n\n"
                            android:text="Dear Parents,"
                            android:textSize="14sp" />


                    </RelativeLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```